# Go bufio ReadString in loop is infinite

Tags: go

I have the next code:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://www.google.com")

if err != nil{
    panic(err)
}

r := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)

for v, e := r.ReadString('\n'); e == nil; {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

So, I want to read responce body in loop but reader `r` reads first line of `Body` infinitely.

While in the same time, this code works fine:

```
v, e := r.ReadString('\n')
for e == nil {
    fmt.Println(v)
    v, e = r.ReadString('\n')
}
```

Can someone explain why the first solution has such behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

> [Package bufio](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/)
>
> ```
> import "bufio"
> ```
>
> [func (*Reader) ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString)
>
> ```
> func (b *Reader) ReadString(delim byte) (string, error)
> ```
>
> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter. If ReadString encounters an error before finding a
>   delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error
>   itself (often io.EOF). ReadString returns err != nil if and only if
>   the returned data does not end in delim. For simple uses, a Scanner
>   may be more convenient.

---

This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Why didn't you take the advice, "For simple uses, a Scanner may be more convenient", given in the `bufio.ReadString` documentation?

Proper use of `bufio.ReadString` is complicated, even when you know how to use `for` loops. See function `reader`.

Proper use of `bufio.Scannner` is simple, even if you don't know how to use `for` loops. See function `scanner`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func reader(url string) error {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // ReadString
    r := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)
    for {
        line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        if len(line) == 0 && err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }
        line = strings.TrimSuffix(line, "\n")

        fmt.Println(line)

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func scanner(url string) error {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Scanner
    s := bufio.NewScanner(resp.Body)
    for s.Scan() {
        line := s.Text()

        fmt.Println(line)

    }
    if s.Err() != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    url := "https://www.example.com"
    fmt.Println("\nReader:\n")
    err := reader(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    fmt.Println("\nScanner:\n")
    err = scanner(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    fmt.Println("\n")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/e0WY_aNxW8

Answer (score 2):

Structure of the loop is:

```
for init; condition; post { }
```

The `init` part of the loop is called only once, at the beginning. That means that the...

```
v, e := r.ReadString('\n')
```

...part from your loop is called only once, which explains why your loop implementation reads only the first line from `r` and why `e` is always `nil`, resulting in an infinite loop.

---

You may want to do something like this instead:

```
for v, e := "", (error)(nil); e == nil; {
    v, e = r.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Or if that looks weird to you, something like this:

```
var v string
var e error
for ; e == nil; {
    v, e = r.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

More info here:

- https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements

Comment: Let me guess. You know Perl as well :)